# Unity problem after upgrading to 12.04 (Blank desktop, no dash, no menu bar)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have updated Ubuntu to 12.04.The process completed without any error but after restarting I could log in to my account but it showed an empty desktop left.

I read all related questions in askubuntu and tried all the answers but nothing worked properly. I found some answers using  *** Alt+Ctrl+F1*** but when I pressed this buttons the desktop was gone and I was left with a message on the monitor saying **"OUT OF RANGE   92.6kHz / 58Hz"** so I can't use the answers with those keys.. I had that problem when I upgraded to 11.04.

When I start my system after the motherboard startup screen came the above message comes and it lasts till the log in screen appears. There is no other problems apart from this error message.

Please help me with these problem.