# Why doesn't Gnome 3.4.1 installed from PPA on 12.04 load?

Tags: desktop-environments

i've just installed gnome 3.4.1 on my ubuntu 12.04, but when I log on to it, as GNOME, the only thing showning is the background image. No icons, bottom panel, or launcher. Nothing at all.
I've read that it's necessary to start with Gnome, rather than Gnome Classic, to install shell extensions such as the frippery applications menu.
 I hope that I can make myself understood, english is not my first language and i'm new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a top task bar gnome 3 is very diffrent to gnome 2

also can you activate the app switcher by pushing your mouse to the top left corner of the desplay try it and let me know

Comment: I don't have the top task bar. It's really just the background image, and the cursor also appears.

Comment: I looked round the site and found this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128726/unity-problem-after-upgrading-to-12-04-blank-desktop-no-dash-no-menu-bar) hope its what you need